# Equating a 2D array to a value

Tags: c, cs50

im running doing runoff from cs50 and i dont understand one part of the solution

```
// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            /*
            update the preferences 2d array to indicate
            the voter has that cand as their rank n
            */ 
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            // preferences[1][j] = rank;
            printf("voter: %d\n", voter);
            printf("rank: %d\n", rank);
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

The part where they equate preferences[voter][rank] to a value i, what does equating a 2d array do?

Comment: `preferences[voter][rank]` is not a two-dimensional array. Presumably, `preferences` is either a two-dimensional array or something we can use as such. Then `preferences[voter]` is one of the subarrays in that two-dimensional array and `preferences[voter][rank]` is a element of that array. It is probably an `int` or another integer type. Have you worked on earlier lessons in CS50 that taught about arrays?

Comment: You are _assigning_ the value stored in `i` to `preferences[voter][rank]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why? Here we have no idea what `preferences` is or what is being passed as `voter`, `rank` and `name`. Providing a MRE will allow definite answers to this, and your future questions.